# In java, what is the best way to set each value in an int [ ] randomly without duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, random, duplicates

I am fairly new to coding, with around 4 months of experience and self taught. I've used arrays and understand how you write them. But for this specific instance, I am looking to make the values in an array of 15 ints set between the number 1 and 15, without any duplicate values.

If I could be pointed in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.  There are many questions already there which can handle your problem.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Integer> integers = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true) {
            integers.add((r.nextInt(16 - 1) + 1));

            if (integers.size() == 15)
                break;
        }

        int arr[] = new int[integers.size()];

        int i = 0;
        for (int num : integers) {
            arr[i++] = num;
        }
        
        //arr now contains 15 random numbers with no duplicates, do whatever you need with it.
    }